# How to disable text selection on TAB-key focus

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

**ExtJS 4.1**

I have 2 textfields like:

```
                {
                    fieldLabel: 'Email',
                    name: 'email',
                    vtype: 'email',
                }, {
                    fieldLabel: 'Phone',
                    name: 'phone',
                    minLength: 8,
                    maxLength: 20,
                    value: '+7',
                },
```

As you can see `phone` field has predefined value.

When I finish filling `email` fileld, I press TAB key to focus next field (in my case - `phone` field).

When `phone` field is being focused by TAB key cursor incfield stands in the end of value (`+7|`) but all the text in the field **becomes selected** so if I type something all the text is replaced by new text.

I want cursor to stand in the end of the value string and value text would **NOT TO BE SELECED**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround that works:

```
{
    fieldLabel: 'Phone',
    name: 'phone',
    minLength: 8,
    maxLength: 20,
    value: '+7',
    listeners: {
        focus: function(field){
            var value = field.getValue();
            Ext.Function.defer(field.setRawValue, 1, field, [value]);
        }
    }
}
```

Causes a page reflow that sets the caret at the end of the field due to the value being set, should work for ya and doesn't cause a change event.

Comment: No, that is not right. I guess you intended to use the `setRawValue` method cause the `setValue` method will trigger change & validation events! Not to mention that this is a native browser problem and not ExtJS made. Anyway, this is the way I do it. Fix the mentioned issue and you have my +1

Comment: I've tested it and the change event is not fired with 4.1, the change event will only fire if the value does change, which in this case you are just resetting it to the same value.  Either way, the setRawValue probably is safer assuming it works.

Comment: Have you tested the setRawValue method?  I will change if you can assure me that it works.

Comment: It does the same,but without Triggering any validation

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this.

```
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Phone',
                name: 'phone',
                minLength: 8,
                maxLength: 20,
                value: '+7',
                listeners:{
                     focus:function(t,e){
                       t.selectText(t.getValue().length,t.getValue().length);
                     }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some Chrome behaviour. It's automatically selects all the text in the next text input on TABing.

Tried all the solutions posted and no effect in Chrome (Opera and Mozilla works fine).

Thanks all for taking time!

Answer (score 0):

The key to beating this problem is using setTimeout or something similar to @Reimius' answer.

Chrome and IE selects all text on focus, even if you call `event.stopPropagation()`.

Possible solution (some jQuery used):

```
var selectText;

selectText = function(element, startIndex, endIndex) {
  var range;

  // Modern browsers, IE9+
  if (element.setSelectionRange != null) {
    element.selectionStart = startIndex;
    element.selectionEnd = endIndex;
    return;
  }

  // OldIE
  range = element.createTextRange();
  range.collapse(true);
  range.moveEnd('character', endIndex);
  range.moveStart('character', startIndex);
  range.select();
};

$(document).on('focus', 'input textarea', function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    selectText(input, selectionStartIndex, selectionEndIndex);
  }, 0);
});
```